# Side by side divs that aren't centering and aren't conforming to content

Tags: css

I am trying to put two divs side by side in a wordpress theme. A slider is on one side (left) and three images that will be banners of the sort is on another (right).

The issue I'm encountering is (1) The div won't center and (2) on larger monitors the divs don't conform to the content. I guess the best way to describe it is they don't collapse with the content while remaining responsive. So if I have the div width as a percentage to keep things responsive the divs don't collaspe but if I make the width of the divs auto they conform to the content.

This is my site  http://jesuspeople.personalityweb.com/ so you can see what I'm saying.
Here is my CSS for my div

```
.mydiv{
position: relative;
display:inline-block;
/*position: absolute;*/
width: 100%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: auto !important;
/*height: 650px !important;*/
/*border: thin solid red;*/
background-image: url("http://jesuspeople.personalityweb.com/
wp-content/uploads/2016/10/gradient-new-2.jpg");
background-repeat:repeat-x;
overflow: hidden;
/*  z-index:-1;*/

}
```

Here's my code on the page for the divs

```
<div class='mydiv'>";
echo "<div style='float:left; width: 75%'>"; 
echo page_slider();
echo"</div><div style='float:right; width: 25%'>
<img src='http://jesuspeople.personalityweb.com/wpcontent/uploads/2016
/10/partner-with-us-1.jpg' />
<img src='http://jesuspeople.personalityweb.com/wp-content/
uploads/2016/10/prophetic-corner-1.jpg' />
<img src='http://jesuspeople.personalityweb.com/wp-
content/uploads/2016/10/miracle-testimonies-1.jpg' />
</div>";
echo"</div>";
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question itself, not a third-party website. Stack Overflow is meant to help everyone with similar problems, not just your immediate problem, and if you fix your problem, that link will no longer be relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you use very old bootstrap so u should follow its grid structure like below this will help ur content align

```
<div class='container'>";

echo "<div class='row';
echo "<div class='span8'; 
echo page_slider();
echo"</div><div class='span8'>

<img src='http://jesuspeople.personalityweb.com/wpcontent/uploads/2016
/10/partner-with-us-1.jpg' />
<img src='http://jesuspeople.personalityweb.com/wp-content/
uploads/2016/10/prophetic-corner-1.jpg' />
<img src='http://jesuspeople.personalityweb.com/wp-
content/uploads/2016/10/miracle-testimonies-1.jpg' /></div>";

echo"</div></div>";
```